# Is there difference between creating a wrapped BigInt or Symbol with the "new" keyword in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, new-operator, bigint

I have examined the wrapped symbol objects using the following code.

```
const symObj = Object(sym);
const symObjNew = new Object(sym);
// I can see no difference between symObj and symObjNew

console.log(`typeof symObj === 'object' is ${typeof symObj === 'object'}`); // true
console.log(`typeof symObjNew === 'object' is ${typeof symObjNew === 'object'}`); // true
```

I have also examined the `symObj` and `symObjNew` in devtools using `node --inspect-brk`. I don't see any difference between them. The same is true of BigInt.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object

Comment: If you want to know what something is, [don't use `typeof`](/a/62155395/740553), because it can only tell you the generic type, not the specific type.

Comment: @StanleyHughes remember to upvote useful answers and accept the answer you were looking for. SO doesn't work if all you do is post a question and then walk away.

Answer (score 2):

## TL;DR

There is no difference between `new Object(realthing)` and `Object(realthing)`. They do the same thing.

## Much longer answer

When it comes to JS, reading the spec is always a good idea, although it can be incredibly hard to figure out what things mean. So, let's dive into this: in this case, we want [the rules for how Object() works](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-fundamental-objects):

> 19.1.1The Object Constructor
>
> The Object constructor:
>
> - is the intrinsic object %Object%.
> - is the initial value of the Object property of the global object.
> - creates a new ordinary object when called as a constructor.
> - performs a type conversion when called as a function rather than as a constructor.
> - is designed to be subclassable. It may be used as the value of an extends clause of a class definition.

So we have two cases to look at: `Object(sym)`, and `new Object(sym)`.

#### What happens for `Object(sym)`?

> 19.1.1.1 Object([ value ])
>
> When the Object function is called with optional argument value, the following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If NewTarget is neither undefined nor the active function, then
>         Return ? OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget, "%ObjectPrototype%").
> 2. If value is null, undefined or not supplied, return ObjectCreate(%ObjectPrototype%).
> 3. Return ! [ToObject(value)](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-toobject).

(Note that `?` and `!` here are not "code", they are spec syntax. `!` means "this operation will always return [a normal value](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-completion-record-specification-type) whereas `?` *may* return an abnormal value)

In this case, we didn't use `new`, so step 1 doesn't apply. The value is not nullish, so step 2 doesn't apply, and we end up executing step 3: we perform a type conversion so we end up with a new object for which `typeof` will now say `"object"`, no matter what it was before, but with the original data preserved as value.

#### What happens for `new Object(sym)`?

Looking at 19.1.1.1 again, we're using `new` this time, so we might expect step 1 to kick in: after all, there is a `NewTarget` (by definition: we used `new` so there is a `NewTarget`), but it turns out the `NewTarget` is the `Object` function itself, making `NewTarget` the active function, and so step 1a does *not* kick in.

We also have a value, and it's not nullish, so step 2 doesn't kick in, and we again run step 3: type conversion.

So `Object(sym)` and `new Object(sym)` do exactly the same thing, just for subtly different reasons.

### So how does ToObject work?

Looking at the spec again:

> 7.1.13ToObject ( argument )
>
> The abstract operation ToObject converts argument to **a value of type Object** according to Table 12:
>
> - `Undefined`  Throw a TypeError exception.
> - `Null`   Throw a TypeError exception.
> - `Boolean`    Return a new Boolean object whose [[BooleanData]] internal slot is set to argument. See 19.3 for a description of Boolean objects.
> - `Number`     Return a new Number object whose [[NumberData]] internal slot is set to argument. See 20.1 for a description of Number objects.
> - `String`     Return a new String object whose [[StringData]] internal slot is set to argument. See 21.1 for a description of String objects.
> - `Symbol`     Return a new Symbol object whose [[SymbolData]] internal slot is set to argument. See 19.4 for a description of Symbol objects.
> - `Object`     Return argument.

So the first observation should be that "if it's an object, ToObject does nothing". That's of course not the case for your `Object(sym)`, so what happens for *it*?

A new object gets built, with its `type` set to `object` (irrespective of what the input value type is), and this new object's *prototype* will be set to match whatever the input value's prototype was. Then the new object's internal *value* literally gets copied over from the input value that's getting converted.

But we're not quite done

### `typeof` is useless for testing "what a thing is".

Remember that almost *everything* in JS is an object, and `typeof` will only tells you [the basic type of something](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-typeof-operator). As such, there are only six answers it can give you:

1. object
2. function
3. string
4. symbol
5. number
6. undefined

That's it. The `typeof` operator tells you nothing about the what the most specific type is, instead it tells you what the most *generic* type is.

For the specific type, either use `thing.constructor.name` to find out which constructor function *actually* got used to build the thing you're examining, or use `thing.__proto__` to get a reference to that type. Or, if you *have* the type already and merely need to test to see if "thing is a ...", use the [instanceof](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-instanceofoperator) operator:

```
> typeof 3
"number"

> typeof Object(3)
"object"

> Object(3).constructor.name
"Number"

> Object(3).__proto__
Number { 0 }

> Object(3) instanceof Number
true
```

Comment: I think this answer would be improved by addressing the differences being asked about between using `new` and not using `new`, especially in your repl snippet.

Comment: I've updated this answer based on conversations with the folks who wrote the spec. And a helpful secondary link: ["How to Read the ECMAScript Specification"](https://timothygu.me/es-howto/)

Answer (score 0):

As specified in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/Object):

> When called in a non-constructor context, `Object` behaves identically to `new Object()`.

I'd venture to guess this is another one of JavaScript's infamous backwards compatibility 'features', back during such a time that the `new` keyword didn't exist.

You can also check the [ECMAScript spec](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-object-constructor) for details:

> When the Object function is called with optional argument *value*, the
>   following steps are taken:
>
> 1. If NewTarget is neither **undefined** nor the active function, then
>
>    1. Return ? `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor(NewTarget, "%Object.prototype%")`.
> 2. If *value* is **undefined** or **null**, return `OrdinaryObjectCreate(%Object.prototype%)`.
> 3. Return ! `ToObject(value)`.

As thoroughly explained by Mike's answer, both cases in your sample snippet end up in Step 3, which performs type conversion on the argument. So there is no difference whatsoever.

Comment: Then MDN might need an update, because [the spec disagrees](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-fundamental-objects). As constructor, it builds a new object. As _function_, it performs a type conversion. And note that after your edit, your two quoted claims now contradict =)

Comment: Right, but there is no `NewTarget`, so we fall through to point (3), which you forgot to add here, which tells us that what actually gets returned is `toObject(value)`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans You may be right, but I can't make much sense of the spec. I can't find where the behavior when it's called *as a constructor* and *with arguments* is defined, only for one or the other or neither.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans It may serve as a conversion, the question is whether that behavior differs with and without the `new` keyword. As far as I can tell, with the `new` keyword the `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor` operation is called, and `value` (what was passed to the constructor) doesn't get passed... yet the actual behavior observed seems to be a type conversion in both cases.

Comment: OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor only kicks in _if_ there is a `NewTarget` to work with, which _only_ exists if `new` was used. That's not the case, so we jump to (3), pure type conversion.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I think you're absolutely correct that calling it *without* `new` acts strictly as a type conversion, my question is how `new Object(3)` results in an `[object Number]` when the spec doesn't seem to clearly define that that should be the observed behavior.

Comment: It most certainly does: https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/index.html#sec-toobject. The `ToObject` call creates something of _type_ "object", with a _prototype_ appropriate to the original value, and with the original value as data.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans **When called with new**, the spec does not seem to pass through `ToObject`, it seems to follows through step 1 in the spec and calls `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor`. Because when called with new, the NewTarget is set to an empty object or the constructor itself or something, i think. Not quite sure how NewTarget works.

Comment: Yes, that's... what the spec says will happen? When called with `new`, (1) happens. If you use `Object(nullish)`, (2) happens. And when using `Object(somethingreal)`, (3) happens. All three steps are "terminal" in that they are the final step in the chain. And for step (1), `NewTarget` works fairly straightforward: using the `new` operator in combination with the various ways JS allows for assignment creates one.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Maybe I haven't explained my question clearly enough. **When it's called with new AND given an argument**, i.e. when we are squarely in case 1 (nothing related with ToObject or other), *what operation* is responsible for the returned object being an `[object Number]` or some other object with different prototype? I am unable to follow the spec in (1) through `OrdinaryCreateFromConstructor` to arrive at this result. As far as I can tell, the argument to the constructor isn't even passed down in case (1). How does the argument's prototype and value affect the result?

Comment: Right, so this turned into a conversation with literally the editor of the spec to figure out what the heck is really doing on, and it turns out the spec is so dense even I'm getting it wrong: 19.1.1.1 step 1 is bypassed, as `NewTarget` exists but _is_ the active function. Then step 2 doesn't apply, and step 3 runs, exactly the same as if `new` was not specified.

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect the information that came out of https://twitter.com/TheRealPomax/status/1267942512284426240

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans Wow, that's really excellent. That definitely clears it up, though I really have to question this usage of "active function". Thanks for doing the digging!

Comment: Yeah I can't say I'm a fan of that term, and the definition for it kind of... isn't one. It's a wall of text that dances around what it really is.